# Failed to generate code for the service reference 'ServiceReference1'

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wcf, windows-phone-7, soap

When I add service reference to my Windows Phone 7 project, I take an error above. I try to uncheck 'reuse types in all referenced assemblies' and update it. Nothing worked, same error. Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: If you're developing on a regular PC for your Win phone project, you can use the svcutil.exe program to generate the code (interface, really) to connect your program to the web service.

Here's a link to the description: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733(v=vs.110).aspx